# Dose Google AppEngine support self-signed cert? (not custom doamin)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, openssl

[Changes to our SSL Certificates](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2013/05/changes-to-our-ssl-certificates.html)

Above link was published by Google. They will upgrade SSL from 1024bit to 2048bit.
But I have a hardware that will send data via Https POST, unfortunately it support 1024bit only...

So, my purpose is let my hardware can handshake with Google through Https with 1024bit SSL cert. I want to use oppenssl to generating a 1024bit rsa to build a self-signed SSL then install on GAE. Is that a workable method?

Answer (score 3):

The docs clearly state that GAE does support self-signed certs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#cert_type

It does not state the minimum length of the key.

Comment: But this doc is for Custom Domain. Can I enable Custom Domain with self-signed cert but reserved the original URL(app-id.appspot.com) that Google provided? Thanks.